# Motor controller for 24v motor, Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield

I need a motor controller for a 24v motor and I want to control it using än Arduino Uno. Suggestions?

The motor needs to run both directions and is going to draw about 5A

Comment: I see, the Arduino Motor Shield only supports upto 12V. But there are motor controllers for 24V and beyond that and can find those on ebay, aliexpress and whatever local suppliers you can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [Arduino Compatible Mega Motor Shield](http://www.robotshop.com/en/arduino-compatible-mega-motor-shield-1a-5-28v.html). Specs:

1. Low-cost robust H-bridge ''shield'' for Arduino
2. Provides the ability to control up to 30A of current at up to 28V
3. Supply voltage: 5V to 28V (24V max battery rating)
4. Continuous output current: 13A
   Have, a look:

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing my own driver dude using Tip122 but you can use TIP120 too [TIP](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/TI/TIP120.pdf)and other components
[image: TIP122 driver]

Comment: Using bipolar power transistors for this is far from the best idea in this day and age.  This is a classic MOSFET application.  Also, since you posted the question has been updated to clarify the need for bidirectional drive, which means two high side switches and two low.

Answer (score 0):

better invest few dollars and use a motor controller that will keep you from shooting threw the MOSFET transistors, enable soft start of motor and let you select between fast decay and slow decay when PWM is in OFF state. ( see details for DRV8814 by TI)